# Tkinter step by step execution fails with 'after'

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm not a really advanced programmer but I usually know how to write the code I want on Python, but I'm not used to Tkinter.
I have a problem when using it.

Basically, I want a line to move gradually toward the clicked pixel, with a certain step. I wanted it to move every 100ms. Here's my code :

```
from tkinter import *
from time import *


Fen=Tk()

def clic(event,i=0):
    global x0
    global y0
    step=10
    x0=x0+(event.x-x0)/step
    y0=y0+(event.y-y0)/step
    zone.coords(J,x0,y0-20,x0,y0+20)
    if i!=step:
        zone.after(100,clic(event,i+1))


zone=Canvas(Fen,width=800,height=500)
zone.pack()
x0=400
y0=250

J=zone.create_line(x0,y0-20,x0,y0+20,width=2)

zone.bind("<Button-3>",clic)

Fen.mainloop()
```

But what happens is that once I right click somewhere on the Canvas, the program freezes for 1 second (corresponding to the step*100ms), and then the line appears at the final position, i.e. where I clicked. I don't understand why the program seems to ignore the "route" of the line.

I hope I was clear enough, 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have a typo in your after call, it should be `zone.after(100,clic,event,i+1)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the move to make calculated from the coordinates clicked on, in order to be able to move towards them step after step.

You also need to determine if the function was called following a mouse event, or via `after` in order to know what to do with the event passed.

```
import tkinter as tk


fen = tk.Tk()

def clic(event, i=0):
    global x0, y0
    step = 10
    if event is not None:
        dxdy[0] = (event.x - x0) / (step + 1)
        dxdy[1] = (event.y - y0) / (step + 1)
    dx, dy = dxdy
    x0 = x0 + dx
    y0 = y0 + dy
    zone.coords(J, x0, y0-20, x0, y0+20)
    if i < step:
        event = None
        j = i + 1
        zone.after(100, clic, event, j)   # <-- after allows parameters to be passed
    else:
        dxdy[0] = None
        dxdy[1] = None

zone = tk.Canvas(fen, width=800, height=500)
zone.pack()
x0 = 400
y0 = 250

J = zone.create_line(x0, y0-20, x0, y0+20, width=2)

dxdy = [None, None]
zone.bind("<Button-1>", clic)

fen.mainloop()
```